# python lxml external entity does not read file names in a directory (file:///), but will grab file (file:///home/text.txt)

Tags: python, xml, python-2.7, entity, lxml

I am using python 2.7 with lxml:

```
parser = etree.XMLParser(load_dtd=True, no_network=False, resolve_entities=True)
xml = etree.parse(data, parser=parser)
```

The resulting xml will parse data with external entities. It will grab files if the external entity is:

```
file:///home/text.txt
```

However, if we want the external entity to be processed to list the files in a directory:

```
file:///home/
```

the external entity variable is blank.

This is a debian machine.

Example that gets a file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlset [
<!ENTITY list SYSTEM "file:///home/test.txt" >]>
<test>
    <game>
        <files>&list;</files>
    </game>
</test>
```

Example that DOES NOT get a list of file names:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE urlset [
<!ENTITY list SYSTEM "file:///home/" >]>
<test>
    <game>
       <files>&list;</files>
     </game>
</test>
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: Added examples above.

Comment: I'm not sure what you expect. An external entity cannot produce a list of filenames from a directory. That is not how it works. `file:///home/` is not a file that contains text.

Comment: This is not a question about XML or lxml. It is a question about walking a tree in the file system vs. reading a single file.

Comment: An external entity should read the list of files at file:///home/ . There are many references to this, for example see the end of step 4 [link](https://blog.h3xstream.com/2014/06/identifying-xml-external-entity.html)

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Do you want to exploit a possible vulnerability to read directory contents? Why?

Comment: No, I am building it on my system. In the browser file:/// will list the contents of the directory, but via lxml it will not.

Comment: Why do you need to use XML entities to show directory contents? `os.listdir()` will list the entries in a directory.